# RxJava: how to extract blocks form a source observable?

Tags: rx-java, partitioning, reactive-streams

I have
`[1,2,3,2,4,5,0,2,1,3,4,5,2,2,1,4,5]`

What I want as output is

```
[[1,2,3,2,4,5],[1,3,4,5],[1,4,5]]
```

This means I want to extract blocks from the input sequence with some start marker, here `1`, and some end marker, here `5`.
Elements in between these blocks are ignored.

Is there a readable combination of `rx-java` operators for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need the `buffer` operator that takes an opening and closing idicator. Since the elements themselves are the indicators, you'll have to `publish` the original sequence and funnel them into the indicators too.

```java
Observable
.fromArray(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5)
.publish(v -> 
    v.buffer(
        v.filter(w -> w == 1), 
        u -> v.filter(w -> w == 5)
    )
)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```